# setBorderPainted, how to preserve effect on hover

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone have any idea how to preserve the effect on hover from `setBorderPainted(true)` without borders? In simple words, I don't want to have a frame around the button until I will hover the mouse on this button. And second question can I change the size of this frame and color?

Comment: Are you re-inventing [`JToolBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#setRollover-boolean-)? And, well, [`setBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-) and [`BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, thickness)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createLineBorder-java.awt.Color-int-)…

Comment: `setBorder` should help you change the color and size of the "frame"

Comment: Nope, I am not re-inventing JToolBar, I am working at simple chess and my idea is to create chess-like movable buttons. So I want to have a clear image of the pawn until I will hover the mouse on him

Comment: Well, buttons needs a parent and when using a `JToolBar` as their parent will give you the intended rollover border behavior, why not use a `JToolBar` as parent?

Comment: You handle mouseEntered/Exited events and set the Border appropriately.